# What is the "array of intensity values" return value of CGColorGetComponents()?

Tags: objective-c, types

`const CGFloat * CGColorGetComponents ( CGColorRef color );`

The Apple documentation says  `CGColorGetComponents()` returns an array of "intensity values". What does it mean by intensity value? Why is its return type not an array but a pointer to `CGFloat` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it says "an array of intensity values" is that it doesn't know what the numbers in the array mean. Their meaning depends upon the color's color space. For example, if it's a greyscale color space, there are two numbers, the amount of whiteness and the amount of transparency. But if it's an RGB color space, there are four numbers, the red, green, blue, and transparency components. And there are many other possibilities.

The reason it's a pointer to CGFloat is that this is a C API, and in C, a pointer to a CGFloat is the same as an array of CGFloat.

Comment: If you don't know C, you can't know Objective-C. You might want to read my book, which teaches you enough C to use Objective-C. Here's the section on arrays: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch01.html#_arrays